# notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't refresh ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have the following problem:

I am trying to load some data from firebase and after the data is loaded and stored in a HashMap I call the "updateAdapter" function (declared in the adapter below) and although the data has being changed the ListView doesn't refresh until some later random-(IMO) moment. I read couple of posts related to my problem and tried different solutions suggested there but they don't fix my problem. And by the way - Yes, I checked if the adapter loses the reference to the list and it doesn't.

My adapter looks like this:

```
public class NoteAdapterHashMap extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();

    public NoteAdapterHashMap(Map<String, Note> map) {
        mData.addAll(map.entrySet());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, Note> getItem(int position) {
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO implement logic with ID
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_listview, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }

        Note note = getItem(position).getValue();
        if(note!=null){
            TextView title = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.list_note_title);
            TextView date = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.list_note_date);
            TextView content = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.list_note_content);
            title.setText(note.getmTitle());
            date.setText(note.getDateFormatted(parent.getContext()));
            content.setText(note.getmContent());

            if(note.getmContent().length()>50){
                content.setText(note.getmContent().substring(0,50));
            }

        }


        return result;
    }
    public void updateAdapter(HashMap<String,Note> map){
        this.mData.clear();
        this.mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where/when are you calling `updateAdapter()`?

Comment: As I mentioned above I call it after the data is loaded from firebase. In other words I store the data from firebase in a HashMap and then call updateAdapter with this new data.